# How to update an existing xml file in AWS S3 using python,

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

i wrote a very simple python code for updating an existing xml file. Now i have to do the same but in AWS S3. Below is my code and tried a bit and no luck. The error is first found in the xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_file). Any experienced ideas..?

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import boto3


s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')    
bucket = s3.Bucket('3d-app')  


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #xml_file = 's3://3d-app/updator/project_detail.xml/'  
    xml_file = os.path.realpath("project_detail.xml")

    xmltree = ET.parse(xml_file)

       #print(xmltree) 
    root = xmltree.getroot()

       #print(root)
       #print(root.tag)

    #root_tag = root.find('root')

    project = ET.SubElement(root, "project")
    indexpage_path = ET.SubElement(project, "indexpage_path")
    description = ET.SubElement(project, "description")
    thumbnail_path = ET.SubElement(project, "thumbnail_path")

    indexpage_path.text ="$(new to be added) "
    description.text = "$(new to be added) "
    thumbnail_path.text = "$(new to be added) "

      #print ((indexpage_path), (indexpage_path.text))
      #print((description), (description.text))

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(xml_file)
    return
```

Comment: It seems likely that the XML file doesn't exist.  What error are you getting?  To read from S3 directly take a look at the [Boto3 S3 docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)

Comment: when i added print(xml_file) it prints /var/task/project_detail.xml

Comment: However the error message is as follows; [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/project_detail.xml': IOError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/myFunction.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
    xmltree = ET.parse(xml_file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/project_detail.xml'

Comment: Your code is reading a local file. But nowhere in your code are you downloading your xml file from S3. You'll need to download the file from S3 to a local file. Only then can you open it.

Comment: Thanks Matt,, forgot to say it has to be a Lambda Function in AWS, so maybe,,, there might be a different approach ..

Answer (score 0):

Please separate the generation of the XML from the storing in AWS S3.

If XML is stored locally in a file, use **set_contents_from_filename()**.
If XML is stored in a string, use **set_contents_from_string()**.

```
AWS_Region = 'eu-west-1'    # use connect_to_region to avoid 301 error
target_bucket = 'your.bucket.com'
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(
        AWS_REGION,
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET,
        is_secure=True,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )
bucket = conn_s3_r.get_bucket(target_bucket)
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = target_key
#if k.exists(): print "File existing, overwriting anyway: ", target_key
k.set_contents_from_filename(src_file)
k.make_public()   #I use this for static website hosted on AWS S3
```